# How to place element inside <div> under each other in css

Tags: html, css

How to place inputs and button under each other in the middle of the page?

[image: Example]

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div className="join-block">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Room ID" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your name" value="" />
    <button class="btn btn-success">Join</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+center+form+elements+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```css
 .wrapper 
 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;     
  }
  .join-block {
      width: 350px;
      border-radius: 5px;       
      margin: 0 auto;   
  }
  input ,button{    
    width:300px;
    padding:10px;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="join-block">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Room ID" />
    <input type="text"  placeholder="Your name" value="" />
    <button class="btn btn-success">Join</button>
  </div>
</div>
```